# Why marginal effect and average marginal effects are the same for NB regression?

Tags: regression, negative-binomial-distribution, marginal-effect

Using the `margins()` function from the `margins` R package, I fitted a negative binomial model (`mod1`).

```
library(MASS)
library(margins)
mod1 <- glm.nb(y ~ x1 + x2, data = dat, link = 'log')

## Marginal effects
summary(mod1)
Call:
glm.nb(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, data = dat, link = "log", init.theta = 0.1745591775)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.3707  -1.2413  -0.6624  -0.0510   3.6058  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)   0.5059     0.7058   0.717   0.4735  
x1            0.5009     0.2063   2.428   0.0152 *
x2            0.4634     0.6092   0.761   0.4469  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(0.1746) family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 211.92  on 214  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 200.48  on 212  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1198.9

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


              Theta:  0.1746 
          Std. Err.:  0.0197 

 2 x log-likelihood:  -1190.8950 

## Average marginal effects
summary(margins(mod1, type = "link", data = dat))
> summary(margins(ngbMod2, type = "link", data = dat))
 factor    AME     SE      z      p   lower  upper
    x1    0.5009 0.2063 2.4279 0.0152  0.0965 0.9052
    x2    0.4634 0.6092 0.7606 0.4469 -0.7306 1.6574
```

Now, if you compare the two cases, the estimated coefficients along with their standard errors are exactly the same. Why does this happen?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are doing the marginal effect on the link scale, and you have a linear additive model, the derivative wrt the variables on the link scale is the same as the coefficient.

It would not be the same if you had an interaction or were computing it on the type="response" scale

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. So, are we saying that marginal effects and AMEs are the same for linear regression?

Comment: The coefficients and AME are the same when the regression is literally linear in x, if that is what you mean. It's not the same if you a linear regression with transformations, polynomial terms, splines, interactions on the x variables. Normally, linear regression only refers to linearity in the betas

Comment: Yes, you got my point. I'm referring to the usual multiple regression. Many thanks!

Comment: Just one final question: What do you suggest to me if I want to use a certain transformed variable? Let's x2' = log(x2). Shall I include as x2' or log(x2) in my model? Actually, the two cases give different AME.

Comment: They would be a different AME, because they are different models depending on what you choose. The best choice depends on the "true" data generating process. Generally transformation choices are motivated by the domain, and what fits the data. It's even possible to include both.